# Overpass: Search for POIs in a given perimeter

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Using [overpass-turbo.eu](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) I want to query different types of elements near a certain point. Here's an example which returns all trees 150 meters around Big Ben in London.

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
( 
  node[name="Big Ben"]["addr:street"="Bridge Street"];
  node(around:150)[natural=tree];
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

It works for all trees. But what if I for example also want to find all shops 150 meters from Big Ben? Due to overpass' flow concept, I can use the Big Ben node only for the query next to the line where I've queried for Big Ben.

What I may need to do is to store Big Ben's node in a variable to access it for all queries following. How does this work?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Extending your bbox by +5 kilometers should already solve your problem, doesn't it? Also, the [Overpass API Language Guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide) explains how to search by rough location and by distance (see `around`).

Comment: @scai: the Language Guide doesn't cover this topic (it's really outdated). What is needed here is described in the [Overpass QL](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Relative_to_other_elements_.28around.29) documentation as around with radius and lat/lon center point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the following Overpass syntax:

```
(around:radius,latitude,longitude)
```

In this case:

```
node(around:150, 51.50069, -0.12458)[natural=tree];
```

Comment: The link to learnoverpass just points to a copy of the original documentation, which can be found at [Overpass QL](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Relative_to_other_elements_.28around.29), as I mentioned in my previous comment.